# How to get current page name in my wordpress plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I am creating a custom wordpress plugin.

Where for some pages like

http://example.com/clinic

http://example.com/pharmacy

i will append my template code from my plugin folder. Which mean i will include my custom template not even related to wordpress theme.

my code will look like this inside my wordpress plugin page.

```
if ( $wp->query_vars('pagename')=="clinic"){            
    include(MYPLUGINPATH . '/template/clinic.php');
    die();
}else if($wp->query_vars('pagename')=="pharmacy"){
    include(MYPLUGINPATH . '/template/clinic.php');
    die();
}
```

But $wp-query_vars('pagename') return null.is there a way to get the current loading wordpress pagename inside the plugin code.

Comment: Can you provide more information? For example, what is `$wp`? Are you using that code in some action hook? If so, which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `$pagename` global variable 
or pull it from the url

```
$slug = basename(get_permalink());
```

or grab the title before the loop starts:

```
$page_title = $wp_query->post->post_title;
```